# Multiple relation with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

i have two model 'Asset' ,  and 'User' .'Asset' can be assigned to one 'user' and 'asset' is created by one 'user'.here is detail of model classes

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :assigned_to ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :assets
end
```

now in assets show.html.erb i can access name of creator with

```
 @asset.creator.name
```

but i can not see name of 'assigned_to'

```
@asset.assigned_to.name  #gives nothing
```

both values are successfully saved in database.what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally my problem is solved here is solution

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name=>'User' 

end
```

and

```
user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :created_assets, :foreign_key => 'creator_id', :class_name => 'Asset'
has_many :assigned_assets , :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id', :class_name => 'Asset'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the values directly to console:

```
puts @asset.pretty_inspect
puts @asset.assigned_to.pretty_inspect
```

Something;s not right :)

Comment: undefined method `pretty_inspect' for #<Asset:0xb694e40c>

Comment: i am new to rails i have tries in console and i thins all is well in console. console result is   user=User.new=>  #<Userd:nil,:name:nil>\n user.id=2  user.name='foo'   user.inspect=>"#<User id: 2,name:\"foo\">   asset=Asset.new :name='mobile'=> #<Asset id: nil,name: "mobile">   asset.creator=user=>#<User id: 2,name:\"foo\">  means fine   asset.assigned_to=user=> same as above ok now  asset.creator.name=>"foo"   asset.assigned_to.name=>"foo" i think in console we explicitly assign value of relation so works and in development ActiveRecord (am i right?) do this job.

Comment: First -- don't assign .id = 2 yourself, ActiveRecord will do it for you when you save: "user.save!".

Second -- you must do the assign in the rails app the same way as the console.  However, if you've generated the scaffold you'll see something like "User.update_attributes(params[:user])" which will contain all the form fields.  You just need to ensure you have the form-field for :assigned_to added to your form.

Something like:

    <%= select("asset", "assigned_to_id", User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>

Comment: ...and if you're already doing something like that, my original answer applies -- just output it in the view to trace -- "<%= @asset.assigned_to.inspect %>"

Comment: thanks for reply yes assigned_to is present and its value is also saved in database with other form fields.my question was as we can access name of creator by @asset.creator.name but i can't access name of assigned_to user by @asset.assigned_to.name it give error undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClas i also tries @asset.assigned_to_id.name=>(error is) undefined method `first_name' for 1:Fixnum
.  i think there is some problem with association b/w user and asset model.

Comment: my models are class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
{
  //validation
belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name=>'User' ,:foreign_key=>'assigned_to_id'
} and class User < ActiveRecord::Base
{
//any validation and other stuff
 has_many :assets #did not specify either this association    #is    for creator , or assigned to how can is specify this??
} now problem is to specify two has_many :assets in User member on for creator and other for assigned to what is syntax for that or a better solution